# Proof of Fermat primes and constructible n-gon

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that if a regular n-gon is constructible, then $n = 2^kp_1 ···p_r $ where $p_1,...,p_r$ are distinct Fermat primes using the following facts.

1. If the regular $n$-gon is constructible and $n = qr$, the regular $q$-gon is also constructible.
2. If $\xi = \cos(2\pi/p^2) + i \sin(2\pi/p^2)$ then $\xi$ is a root of $f(x)=1+x^p +x^{2p} +···+x^{(p−1)p}$. And $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I proved both of these facts, but I'm having trouble seeing how they help me prove the first statement. I think I'm supposed to use the following theorem, but I'm not sure: "If $p$ is a prime for which a regular $p$-gon is constructible, then $p$ is a Fermat prime.

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen/shown that if a complex number is constructible, then the degree of its minimal polynomial is a power of two?

Comment: I have not seen that theorem. @Servaes

Comment: The point is that when you find a point of intersection of two lines, you are solving a linear equation. OTOH is you find the point of intersection of a circle and another circle or a line, you are solving a quadratic. Thus each step in a compass-ruler construction either stays in the same field or goes to a quadratic extension. You start (essentially) with the rationals, so only ever reach extensions of degrees $2^n$. Mind you, you won't reach even all of those, but it is a necessary condition.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen would you mind elaborating in an answer? I see what you're saying but I'm not sure how to complete the proof with that fact.

Comment: Textbook stuff. Look up, for example, Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*. I suspect most other books with chapters on field extensions cover this as well.

Comment: (I)...Suppose $ p$ is an odd prime and $p^2|n$ Then a regular $p^2$-gon is constructible. (If $n>p^2$  let $m=n/p^2$ and take every $m$th vertex of the regular $n$-gon.)...But $\exp(2\pi i/p^2)$ is of degree $p(p-1)$ over $\Bbb Q$ and $p(p-1)$ is not a power of $2$. Contradiction... (II). If a regular $A$-gon and a regular $B$-gon are constructible with $A,B$  co-prime, take $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ such that $Ax+By=1.$ Then the angle $x(2\pi/B)+y(2\pi/A) =2\pi/AB$ is constructible so a regular $AB$-gon is constructible.

Comment: It is still not known whether there is a Fermat prime  larger than $F(4)=2^{2^4}+1=65537.$

Comment: A few days ago I read “Symmetry”by Hermann Weyl where he described “Gauss' construction of the regular 17 -gon with ruler and compass, which  he  found  as  a  young  lad  of nineteen”. I heard that Gauss was so proud of this result that he will to carve the regular 17-gon on his tombstone. Here are relevant pages of Weyl’s book with a semipopular explanation: [140](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSXT.png), [141](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfyOH.png), [142](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp0TH.png), [143](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2eAv.png).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I'm not sure what you're trying to prove. Would you mind elaborating?